# mongodb with laravel 10 and php8

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, xampp, laravel-10

When I make the command:

```
$ composer require jenssegers/mongodb
```

I got this problem:

```
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update jenssegers/mongodb
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.8] require illuminate/support 4.0.x -> found illuminate/support[v4.0.0, ..., v4.0.10] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v1.1.0, ..., v1.3.2] require illuminate/support 4.1.* -> found illuminate/support[v4.1.0, ..., v4.1.30] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v1.4.0, ..., v1.4.3, v2.0.0, ..., v2.0.5] require illuminate/support 4.2.* -> found illuminate/support[v4.2.1, ..., v4.2.17] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v2.1.0, ..., v2.1.5] require illuminate/support 5.0.* -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.0.33] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v2.1.6, ..., v2.1.9] require illuminate/support ^5.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.0.0, ..., v5.8.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v2.2.0, ..., v2.3.5, v3.0.0, ..., v3.2.3] require illuminate/support ^5.1 -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.8.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v2.2.7, ..., v2.2.10] require illuminate/support ~5.1.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.1.41] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v3.3.0, ..., v3.3.2] require illuminate/support ^5.5 -> found illuminate/support[v5.5.0, ..., v5.8.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v3.4.0, ..., v3.5.0] require illuminate/support ^5.6 -> found illuminate/support[v5.6.0, ..., v5.8.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v3.5.1, ..., v3.5.3] require illuminate/support ^5.8 -> found illuminate/support[v5.8.0, ..., v5.8.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v3.6.0, ..., v3.6.8] require illuminate/support ^5.8|^6.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.8.0, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v3.7.0, ..., v3.7.3] require illuminate/support ^7.0 -> found illuminate/support[v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v3.8.0, ..., v3.8.5] require illuminate/support ^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v3.9.0, ..., v3.9.5] require illuminate/support ^9.0 -> found illuminate/support[v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.5] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires jenssegers/mongodb * -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v1.0.0, ..., v1.4.3, v2.0.0, ..., v2.3.5, v3.0.0, ..., v3.9.5].

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require jenssegers/mongodb:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require jenssegers/mongodb:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

So I did some research and I got a solution to install the driver of php
and when I install it and change the php.ini
and I restart the server xampp
MongoDB is not added in php.info
that is why I cannot run the command

```
$ composer require jenssegers/mongodb
```

to start my work

Comment: What is your laravel version and php version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thank u guys for your questions 
i found the solution the solution is: to install from this website https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/releases/tag/1.15.0

this " php_mongodb-1.15.0-8.1-ts-x64.zip" 
and then when i run the command jessengers and mongodb all is working good

Comment: You are using Laravel 10, but jenssegers/mongodb package currently (at the time of writing this) does not have any stable versions that support Laravel 10.  There is a new released planned soon with support for laravel 10, but no release date announced.
You can check versions compatibility here: https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB#laravel-version-compatibility

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install jenssegers/mongodb in Laravel 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75577962/cant-install-jenssegers-mongodb-in-laravel-10)